# splitting the result of a map returns unexpected array output

Tags: javascript, map-function

I have been trying to solve this for far too long. Can someone explain why none of my attempts below will produce the value I expected?

goal is: transResult=[[xy,zy],[xz,zz]]

```
let allData='xy|zy\r\nxz|zz'
console.log('first split: '+allData.split(/\r?\n/)[0])     
//first split: xy|zy
let transResult=allData.split(/\r?\n/).map(x=>x.split(/|/))
console.log(transResult)
//[ [ 'x', 'y', '|', 'z', 'y' ], [ 'x', 'z', '|', 'z', 'z' ] ]
```

If I split one element eg

```
console.log('xy|zy'.split('|'))
```

I get the expected value of `[ 'xy', 'zy' ]` What is happening with the first map() that is screwing up the result in the first section of code?

Comment: `|` is a special character in regex, you'll need to escape it: `x.split(/\|/)`

Comment: @NickParsons cant believe I forgot that.... please propose it as an answer (unless you would prefer I close the question)

Comment: no worries ;). I think this falls under typo-like questions (as you said, you simply forgot to escape it) and is solved by adding one character, so maybe it's better if it's closed

Answer (score 1):

`|` is a special character so you have to escape it using `\`:

```js
const allData='xy|zy\r\nxz|zz';  
const transResult=allData.split(/\r?\n/).map(x=>x.split(/\|/));

console.log(transResult);
```